# Exception when trying to retrieve child elements of paragraphs in google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I have been trying to deal with the set of images in a document using google apps script. I manage to do what I want, which is to take the images from my document and place them inside a table with two lines and a column, where the first line contains a space for the image description and the second contains the image itself. However, I am having difficulties when going through the paragraphs of my document, my script finds a paragraph without children. This has generated a runtime exception as follows: Exception: The child index (0) must be less than the number of child elements (0). I tried to handle this with an if (), but when I reach the empty paragraph, the same exception is thrown.
The code of my script follows below:

```js
function manipuleImage(){
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var paragraphs = body.getParagraphs();
  
  var imagens = body.getImages();
  var image = imagens[0];
  var typeImage = image.getType();

  for(var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++){

    var paragraph = paragraphs[i];
    
     if(paragraph.getChild(0) != 0){
      var child = paragraph.getChild(0);
      var typeChild = child.getType();
    
      if(typeChild == "INLINE_IMAGE"){
      
         var cells = [
           [''],['']
         ]; 
  
         var styleCell = {};
         styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 11;
         styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
         styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = '#ffffff';
         styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY]='Roboto';
         styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.VerticalAlignment.CENTER;
         styleCell[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER;
  
       var tableImage = body.insertTable(i, cells)
       tableImage.getRow(0).getCell(0).setBackgroundColor("#ef5350");
       tableImage.setBorderColor("#ef5350");
       tableImage.setBorderWidth(1);
       tableImage.getRow(0).getCell(0).setAttributes(styleCell);
       tableImage.getRow(1).getCell(0).setAttributes(styleCell);
       tableImage.getRow(0).getCell(0).setTextAlignment(DocumentApp.TextAlignment.NORMAL);
       tableImage.getRow(1).getCell(0).setTextAlignment(DocumentApp.TextAlignment.NORMAL);
  
       var appendImage = tableImage.getRow(1).getCell(0).clear().appendImage(child.getBlob());
      
       var index = i + 1;
  
       body.removeChild(body.getChild(index));
  
       var imageH = appendImage.getHeight() / 2;
       var imageW = appendImage.getWidth() / 2;
    
       appendImage.setHeight(imageH).setWidth(imageW);
     }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- `getChild(childIndex)` returns Element object. Please be careful this.
- In this case, I think that when the paragraph is only line break, the error occurs. I think that the reason of your issue might be this.

If you want to skip the paragraph which has only the line break, how about ths following modification?

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
if(paragraph.getChild(0) != 0){
```

To:

```
if(paragraph.getNumChildren() != 0){
```

#### References:

- [getChild(childIndex)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#getchildchildindex)
- [getNumChildren()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#getnumchildren)

Comment: It worked perfectly @Tanaike. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Leonardo Silva Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.